# Let client pull data from SQL Server database through windows service and odbc

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I am currently trying to create an mmorpg through Unity.

The problem I have right now is creating the server side for this project. I have been searching all over the internet for hours now but couldn't find something to really help me.

Basically in my game I have a login which shall connect to a server (which I wanted to have as a windows service) which then pulls or writes data through odbc from/into a SQL Server database.

I'd be really glad if someone does have some sources or ideas which can lead me to a solution.

Thanks!

Regards,
Rakinare

Comment: And what problem are you having?  There are *lots* of tutorials for connecting to SQL Server from C#.

Comment: The problem I am having is that I want to connect from my client to that server which then executes the request sent from the client. I couldn't really find any tutorial so far that could explain it in a for me understandbale way or just didn't do it as I wanted it.
If you could point me to some tutorials that would be great!

Edit: Basically I want to create different server backends for account/login, world, zones and such stuff.

Comment: Follow a tutorial for making requests from the client to the server.  Then follow a tutorial for making database queries from the server.  Connect those two things together.  Your question as is is too broad.

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying to help, I will research some more (done for the past 2 days now :/) and see if I can find any pieces that I can put together.

Comment: Break the problem down.  Client -> Server (and back), then Server -> DB.  Learn either first, get a solid grasp of it.  To use an analogy, you're trying to build a car without knowing how the engine works or how it connects to the wheels.  Learn to build engines first.  We can help with specific issues you encounter.

Comment: Do you maybe know some good tutorials that can help me learning to create connection from the server to an sql database through odbc? I only found some small snippets from people having trouble creating that but nothing to really put together.

Or maaybe I am just thinking too complex, I don't know.

Comment: ODBC is an antiquated technology.  Don't use it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562348/connect-to-database-c-sharp

Comment: @Amy, albeit ODBC has been around for a while, it is not antiquated. It's the preferred technology to access SQL Server from native (unmanaged) code and is cross-platform. SqlClient is appropriate for .NET applications. OLE DB is unsupported against SQL Server 2014 and later versions.

Comment: From C#, why would he use ODBC over `System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: Thanks for the help Amy! Gonna work through that.

Comment: @Amy: Reason a) Because if using SqlClient you will be bound to Sql Server. Reason b) Who knows for how long SqlClient will be maintainted by microsoft? Maybe they decide to drop support, like they did for oledb (and replaced it by odbc). If you stay with ODBC, you have a better chance that your code will still work in 20 years. Reascon c) ODBC is an open, well documented standard.